# Lag Function to populate missing rows

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to come up with a SQL to get to this data in a Postgres 9.6 database table.

[Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvfJz.png)
I have tried various variations of windows function but none of these seems to work,

Based on input column C3, I am projecting a fourth column C4 and the output should resemble as below.

[Final Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG6pG.png)

How can I accomplish this using SQL? The table can have up to 100 Million records.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get desired output using the following SQL

with t2 as (select c1, c3 from Test_table where c3 is not null)
update  Test_table t1
set c3 = t2.c3
from t2
where t1.c1 <= t2.c1
and t1.c3 is  null;

select 
c1
,c2
,C3
,dense_rank() over(order by c3) cr
from Test_table
order by c1;

Answer (score 0):

Use a window function to select the smallest c3 in a window ordered by c1 descending, but sort the whole output by c1 ascending:

```sql
select c1, c2, c3, min(c3) over (order by c1 desc) as c4 from t order by c1;
```

Comment: This didn't give me the desired output. C4 picked up 5 as Min.

Comment: That's how your picture shows it, you need to better describe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the SQL provided by you and I get this output. I thought the picture described what I really wanted. Hopefully, showing your output from running your SQL and desired output may help.

[SQL output from your query and desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQbpA.png)